# Invalid column name 'txn_date'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle11g, osb

```
Select a.stmt_date,a.*,b.* from ES_CC_STATEMENTS a left outer join ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS
b on a.stmt_id = b.stmt_id
where a.stmt_cc_number = #cc_number AND (stmt_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, #dateFrom , 
101)) AND (stmt_date < CONVERT(DATETIME, #dateTo , 101)) order by b.txn_date desc
```

I have write this query in Jdeveloper DB-adapter & have buil business service in 
OSB11g when i deploy project & run business server & insert INPUT PARAMETERS i am 
getting following ERROR:

```
The invocation resulted in an error: Invoke JCA outbound service failed with 
application error, exception: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.JCATransportException: 
oracle.tip.adapter.sa.api.JCABindingException: 
oracle.tip.adapter.sa.impl.fw.ext.org.collaxa.thirdparty.apache.wsif.WSIFException: 
servicebus:/WSDL/OSB%20DB%20Adapter/adapter/Jdev_OSB_DBAdapter/test_es_cc_STMT_new [   test_es_cc_STMT_new_ptt::test_es_cc_STMT_new(test_es_cc_STMT_newInput_msg,test_es_cc_STMT_n
ewOutputCollection) ] - WSIF JCA Execute of operation 'test_es_cc_STMT_new' failed due 
to: Pure SQL Exception.

Pure SQL Execute of Select a.stmt_date,a.*,b.* from ES_CC_STATEMENTS a left outer join 
ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS b on a.stmt_id = b.stmt_id where a.stmt_cc_number = ? AND 
(a.stmt_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 101)) AND (a.stmt_date < CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 
101)) order by b.txn_date desc failed.

Caused by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 
'txn_date'..
; nested exception is:
BINDING.JCA-11633
Pure SQL Exception.
Pure SQL Execute of Select a.stmt_date,a.*,b.* from ES_CC_STATEMENTS a left outer join 
ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS b on a.stmt_id = b.stmt_id where a.stmt_cc_number = ? AND 
(a.stmt_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 101)) AND (a.stmt_date < CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 
101)) order by b.txn_date desc failed.

Caused by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 
'txn_date'..
The Pure SQL option is for border use cases only and provides simple yet minimal 
functionality. Possibly try the "Perform an operation on a table" option instead. This 
exception is considered not retriable, likely due to a modelling mistake. To classify 
it as retriable instead add property nonRetriableErrorCodes with value "-207" to your 
deployment descriptor (i.e. weblogic-ra.xml). To auto retry a retriable fault set 
these composite.xml properties for this invoke: jca.retry.interval, jca.retry.count, 
and jca.retry.backoff. All properties are integers.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like column `txn_date` does not exist in table `ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS`.

If you provide your schema, it will be easier to see where the problem lies.

Comment: txn_date column is available in the table ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS

Comment: USE [info]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS]
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS](
 [TXN_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 [TXN_CREATED_ON] [varchar](max) COLLATE   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_TRANSACTION_TYPE] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_FLAG_DEBIT_CREDIT] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_POSTING_DATE] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,

Comment: [TXN_DESCRIPTION] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_AMOUNT] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXT_CURRENCY_CODE] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_FOREIGN_TRANSACTION] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [STMT_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,

Comment: [TXN_FOREIGN_CURRENCY_CODE] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_FOREIGN_CURRENCY_AMOUNT] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_CARD_NUMBER] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_GRP_SEQ_NUM] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_DESC_LINE1] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_DESC_LINE2] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,

Comment: [TXN_DESC_LINE3] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_DESC_LINE4] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_REF_NUM] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_MERCHANT_CODE] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_APPROVAL_CODE] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_SEQ_NUM_IN_GRP] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXT_CARD_INDICATOR] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [TXN_DATE] [timestamp] NULL,

Comment: CONSTRAINT [PK_ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [TXN_ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
USE [info]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ES_STMT_TRANSACTIONS_ES_CC_STATEMENTS] FOREIGN KEY([STMT_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ES_CC_STATEMENTS] ([STMT_ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE